# Mantis Installing Error on Mysql

Tags: mysql, installation, mantis

I tried to install the latest version of Mantis, but i keep getting this error:

```
APPLICATION ERROR #401

Database query failed. Error received from database was #1146: Table 'user_mantis.mantis_user_table' doesn't exist for the query: SELECT *
FROM mantis_user_table
WHERE username=?.

Please use the "Back" button in your web browser to return to the previous page. There you can correct whatever problems were identified in this error or select another action. You can also click an option from the menu bar to go directly to a new section.
```

Im sure about the database credentials, i cant figure out what else would it be.

Appreciate your help!

Comment: Can you add some more information like operating system, MySQL version, PHP version and your config_inc.php file?

Comment: Check manually in the database, if you have a `user_mantis.mantis_user_table`?

Comment: To add to that, I'd make sure that `mantis_user_table` does indeed belong to the `user_mantis` schema. That table may exist but on another schema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the solution at the below mentioned link

http://www.mantisbt.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=19060&p=43806

Let me know if this works for you.